# MongoDB setup on NUMA machine

Tags: centos7, mongodb

I installed MongoDB 3.6 on my centos 7 machine and in the startup log I see a warning because I am running NUMA hardware:

```
2018-02-05T00:13:23.889+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.
2018-02-05T00:13:23.889+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:
2018-02-05T00:13:23.889+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **              numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]
```

I wonder how I could permanently fix this numactl startup as I don't want to start mongod manually every time. I usually run `sudo service mongod start` and I want that this command starts MongoDB every time with the numctl prefix.

How can I achieve this with CentOS7? (I googled and couldn't find any service files I could edit on my server).

Answer (score 2):

On mine using CentOS 7.6 is at

`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongod.service`

Answer (score 1):

A previous "service with numactl" question  [How do I run a service with numactl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187474/how-do-i-run-a-service-with-numactl)  happens to be about mongodb.  Given CentOS 7, the systemd example is relevant, specifically:

Editing `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/numactl.conf`  to override the exec:  `ExecStart=/usr/bin/numactl --interleave=all -- /usr/local/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run`

Another design option would be to split up your NUMA host into VMs no larger than one node each. Mongo has a clustering capability, although that would be more complex than scaling up.  Although, scaling up is not very difficult. And if most VMs ran from one host, there might be a single point of failure.

Comment: There is unfortunately no folder called "service" under `/etc/systemd`.

Comment: Oops, `/etc/systemd/system/`  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In first instance be sure that numa is installed and loaded during the startup:

```sh
yum search numa | egrep -v devel
# Be sure to install the necessary package, avoid the "devel" ones
yum install numad # numactl
```

Be sure that numad is loaded during the startup:

```sh
systemctl enable numad
service numad start
service numad status
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode
sudo sysctl -w vm.zone_reclaim_mode=0
cat /var/log/numa*
```

Now that the enviroinment is ready:

```sh
numactl --interleave=all <path> <options>
```

The `path` is the path to the program you are starting and the  are any optional arguments to pass to the program.

Have a look here for further clarification:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#mongodb-and-numa-hardware